# RichTextBox ignores newlines

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am reading from an XML file and updating a RTB as you could see. This happens during form load. The trouble is the newlines aren't getting processed properly. The RTB is supposed to show urls generated by my application previously and since the newlines get ignored the url's get completely mangled like this:

> `http://XXXXXXXXX.com/Roberto/XXXXXXXXX.pdfhttp://xxxxxxxxxx.com/Roberto/xxxxxx.pdf`

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  tabControl1.SelectTab("tabPage1");
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(Path.GetTempPath() + "/Uploads.xml");
  XmlNodeList nl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Uploads");
  foreach (XmlNode node in nl)
  {
    richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + node.InnerText + 
                                                  Environment.NewLine +"\t");  
  }
  this.listBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragDrop);
  this.listBox1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(this.listBox1_DragEnter);
}
```

XML file

```
<Uploads>
  <upload>http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/Roberto/xxxxxxxxx.pdf</upload>
  <upload>http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/Roberto/xxxxxxxxx.pdf</upload>
</Uploads>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't in your XML file?  Have you stepped through the foreach loop, is each URL in a separate string?

Comment: Yes, definitely. What is scarcely believable is it was getting processed correctly yesterday when I left from work. Today I come in, everything is the same but RTB behaves differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you need to enable the `Multiline` property on your RTB. You can do this in the property tab in form designer, or in code as shown below.

```
richTextBox1.Multiline = true;
```

**EDIT**

The problem is the below line. You need to select "upload" elements not the single "Uploads" parent tag

```
XmlNodeList nl = doc.GetElementsByTagName("upload");
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the URL here on my question is getting displayed in a single line. Multiline is set to true and I am unable to get it to display here properly(as it gets displayed in my RTB). To give you an idea. On line1 3/4 of the first url is displayed, rest 1/4 gets wrapped to the next line and is displayed together with the 2nd url as 1 string.

Comment: Can you include a snippet from your actual XML in your question body?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the same issue, and yes:

1. I set the Richtextbox to Multiline and Wordwrap
2. I have tried several newline characters including System.Environment.Newline

On a Microsoft Blog related to a different Product I found a workaround of using a TextBox instead. You can set this to Multiline, too. 
When I set the boxes' Text to the String including line-breaks they are correctly displayed now.

Seems to be a bug? For me the workaround is fine for now, as I do not need formatting.

Regards,
Matthias